# How to Select latest record in table of Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have Azure SQL database. There are 100 rows in table.

I have columns CustomerName, SalesAmount, SalesTime in CustomerSales table.

```
'Nissan','20000','2021-11-19 17:00:27.9866667'
'Nissan','25000','2021-11-02 17:00:27.9866667'
'Tesla' ,'60000','2021-11-01 17:00:27.9866667'
```

...

I would like make select query which returns single row of latest like
'Nissan','20000','2021-11-19 17:00:27.9866667'

How?

Comment: The newest row `WHERE customername='Nissan'` or the newest rows each `WHERE customer name IN('Nissan','Tesla')`? the first would be easy, the second not so, but possible

Answer (score 0):

Order the rows in descending order by sales time, and then get first returned row only.

For example:

```
select top 1 *
from t
order by SalesTime DESC
```